# Can't Change Height of "div lines" for Hamburger Menu

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to create hamburger menu with 3 divs inside of it that function as 3 lines that I will later animate on close and open. I don't understand how to make my divs visible (e.g. change height property).

My SCSS:

```
.navbar {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .hamburger-menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: coral;

    .menu {
      height: inherit;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-around;
      cursor: pointer;

      &-line {
        width: 100%;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: white;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My JSX Component:

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import styles from "../../styles/layout/navigation.module.scss";

const Navigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={styles["navbar"]}>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" className={styles["checkbox"]} />
        <div className={styles["hamburger-menu"]}>
          <label htmlFor="check" className={styles["menu"]}>
            <div className={styles["menu-line menu-line-1"]}></div>
            <div className={styles["menu-line menu-line-2"]}></div>
            <div className={styles["menu-line menu-line-3"]}></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Fragment>{props.children}</Fragment>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

To clarify, these are the divs i refer to as lines:

```
<div className={styles["menu-line menu-line-1"]}></div>
<div className={styles["menu-line menu-line-2"]}></div>
<div className={styles["menu-line menu-line-3"]}></div>
```

**How do I set the height of my 'lines' (divs)?**

Comment: Based on your SCSS they have a height of 5px so can't you just increase that? Or are you talking about changing the height of the whole thing so they have more space between them?

Comment: It doesn't matter if I increase the height, they are still invisible in the hamburger menu (the div lines have 0 height no matter what value I set to height). I don't want to change the height of the whole thing, just the lines in the menu.

Comment: Have you tried looking in dev tools to see if they have any width? Or if their parent does. That may be causing the issue. They have 100% width and a height value which leads me to believe that their parent element may not have either of the two which is making them not show.

Comment: Yes, I checked in the dev tools and their parent element has a width and height of 40px.

Comment: That is pretty interesting then, and the lines themselves also show having a width and height? Essentially the background-color just seems to not be working and they are invisible?

Comment: So I took your code and remade it in a fiddle and it works perfectly fine https://jsfiddle.net/ba859cxk/ Only thing I changed was removed the coral background and made the lines red so I could see them(those shouldnt matter though)

Comment: Yes, the lines have the wanted width of 40px (100% of parent element) but 0 height.
Thanks for your solution!
It seems it works on fiddle, however, somehow it doesn't work in my NextJS app. Another strange behavior is that when I tested my SCSS in fiddle it still didn't work, I still didn't have the 3 lines I wanted, just the parent element with the coral color.

Comment: So it worked for me right out of the box copying and pasting. Other than changing the lines to red. If copying and pasting my example didn't work what I would do is start peeling dependcies of your app out and see if it starts to work. Essentially strip your app down to just loading your scss and nav and see if it works. Something may be overwriting your styles.

Comment: Same case here, copying your code works just fine for me. If you inspect the lines, is there any other styles applied to it (or the parents)?

Comment: The only dependency I have in my app is the NextJS dependency that supports SASS (npm install sass). Nothing overwrites my styles, however, the '&-line' styles are not being applied at all either? It's like I didn't write this part of the code. It's not only for the height, it's for every property i set to '&-line' style that's not working. Tried changing the width but it didn't work, the div just had 100% width from the beginning.